# citeproc-lua giving errors in luatex

Tags: luatex, citing, texstudio, lua

I use windows 11. I don't konw how to use tex with command prompt. So, i use texstudio. I wanted to use `cep` referencing style in my report, which was not available in `biblatex`, `bibtex`. So, i installed [`cite-proc lua`](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua). while using `cite-proc lua`, Lualatex is giving me errors. I can't even compile the example file provided with `citeproc-lua`.

Note:

I think that there is something wrong with my local texmf directory.

Things i have tried so far:

When i first tried to install `citeproc-lua` with `l3build` install, it gave me errors that it could not write file...etc, because there were white space in my username. Then i created a `texmf` folder in `C:\Users\User's PC` and then it worked (`citeproc-lua` was installed). Then i removed white spaces from my username (changed it to `user`) and again installed `citeproc-lua` with `l3build`.

There was no working local directory at `C:\Users\user` before i installed `citeproc-lua`. I am creating and compiling lualatex documents successfully since around 3 months, so i should have a local working tex directory `C:\Users\User's PC\texmf`, but it was not there, it was somewhere else (i used texstudio and never needed to deal with working directory previously, so didn't know where my working directory was) and i created it while installing  `citeproc-lua`. So, this change in working directory may be causing `citeproc-lua` giving errors, but all the other features of lualatex are running smoothly despite this change of working directory. Only when i use `citeproc-lua`, the lualatex gave errors. So, i uninstalled `citeproc-lua` with the command.

```
l3build make install
l3build uninstall
```

And then again installed `citeproc-lua` with below commands hoping that reinstalling would make errors go away

```
l3build make install
l3build install --full
```

`citeproc-lua` was installed but i am still facing errors. I tried to run below example.

```
%
% Copyright (c) 2021-2022 Zeping Lee
% Released under the MIT License.
% Repository: https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua
%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{citation-style-language}

\cslsetup{style = apa}
\addbibresource{example.json}


\begin{document}

% Single cite item in a citation
\cite{ITEM-1}

% Multiple cite items in a citation
\cite{ITEM-1, ITEM-2}

% Citation with page locator
\cite[page=6]{ITEM-1}

% Citation with volume locator
\cite[volume=3]{ITEM-1}

% Citation with implicit page locator
\cite[6]{ITEM-1}

% Citation with prefix and suffix
\cite[prefix][suffix]{ITEM-1}

% Citation with suffix
\cite[suffix]{ITEM-1}

% Citation with prefix
\cite[prefix][]{ITEM-1}

% Uncited item
\nocite{ITEM-3}

% Uncited all items
\nocite{*}

% Print the reference list
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which is giving me following error message

```
Process started: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "example".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

The log

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lualatex example.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/citeproc-lua-main/example/example.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/citation-style-language/citation-style-la
nguage.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
No file example.aux.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist
/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110:
Module csl Error: Failed to find database file "example.jsonbib" on input line
15

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110: in field 'module_e
rror'
        .../texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl-core.lua:15: in function 'c
sl-core.error'
        .../texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl-core.lua:45: in function 'c
sl-core.read_file'
        .../texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl-core.lua:62: in upvalue 'lo
ad_bib'
        .../texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl-core.lua:81: in function 'c
sl-core.make_citeproc_sys'
        .../texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl-core.lua:117: in function '
csl-core.init'
        .../2021/texmf-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/csl.lua:32: in function 'c
sl.init'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\lua_now:e #1->\__lua_now:n {#1}

l.15 \begin{document}

?
```

I know that question is extremly confusing, so please forgive about that. I am a noob in latex. I have a deadline to submit my report with `cep` reference style, please help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you installed `citeproc-lua` with `l3build`? It would be much better to install it via your TeX distribution (MikTeX Console or TeX Live's `tlmgr`).

Comment: That said, I tried the example from https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/tree/main/example and while I don't get any errors with `\addbibresource{example.json}` there is no meaningful output. I do, however, get what I expect with `\addbibresource{example.bib}`. (Of course I had both `example.json` and `example.bib` in the same directory as `example.tex`)

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing the `json` thing didn't work for me because support for that was only added very recently in an as-of-yet unreleased development version that is only on GitHub but not on CTAN and therefore not in MikTeX or TeX Live.

Comment: I uninstalled `citeproc-lua` with `l3build` and installed it with `tlmgr` still same message `Process exited with error(s)`!, I uninstalled the `citeproc-lua` with `tlmgr uninstall citation-style-language` and again compiled the document. Instead of giving `'citation-style-language.sty' not found`, it is giving me `Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: Post the full `.log` message of the `lualatex` run (with `citation-style-language` etc installed via `tlmgr`).

Comment: log file is very long, so i have uploaded it to mega, you can find it [here](https://mega.nz/file/qiIyhRbY#7fmJUJyoJloS0HuLjKa-HCi-RibaXBGEpyrHW2_-c4E)

It stucks at 

`l.15 \begin{document}

?`

Comment: @David Carlisle its saying `Too long by 1444 characters` if  i try to put it in comments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, there are two seperate files, `example.json` and `example.bib`

Comment: I'm not going to attempt a biblatex answer if @moewe is here:-) and anyway I had not heard of this lua module before but the comment above suggests the json support is new what happens if you use `\addbibresource{example.bib}` and put your data in that file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thankyou I got it running finally
What I did was
- reinstall `citeproc-lua` with `tlmgr`
- changed `example.json` to `example.bib`
- compiled the document and voila!!!

It should be noted that
My original report was successfully rendered after two times compiling it, it did not compile in first time

I think that reinstalling the `citeproc-lua` fourth time solved the problem

Comment: @Hemang it always takes two (or usually three) latex runs before cross references resolve so not having a bibliography on the first run is expected (same as bibtex or biber not specific to lua processing)